# How do I get access to a button inside my Header.xml layout from my MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-navigationview

The problem I am having is that I cannot access the button that I have inside my header xml layout file directly from my MainActivity. The app crashes every time I run it.

I keep getting a NullPointerException point to:

```
MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125)
```

Which is this line of code:

```
mButtonHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

How do I access the button and set an onClick() to it to make it clickable?

**My Header Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/myHeader">
<!--android:background="@drawable/background_material_original"-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:alpha="0.0"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
     /> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**My MainActivity XML layout file:**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHomeBackgroundPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/homebp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home_bp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_home"
    />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My MainActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

  protected Toolbar toolbar;
  protected NavigationView navigationView;
  private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
  protected Button mButtonHeader;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Calling method of my navigation drawer
    setupNavViewDrawer();

     mButtonHeader = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHeader);
     mButtonHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



   }
}
```

**My logcat error:**

```
    10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.pi.cas.ndtc, PID: 14553
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pi.cas.ndtc/com.pi.cas.ndtc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.pi.cas.ndtc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:125)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-31 20:48:05.342 14553-14553/com.pi.cas.ndtc E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Is your header layout named tool_bar? It just doesn't look like you have the xml correctly hooked up to me.

Comment: tool_bar is a separate layout where I defined what the toolbar should be like. I am assuming the toolbar has nothing to do with the current problem

Comment: then there's your problem right there. The MainActivity xml references tool_bar through an include, but not the XML file that contains the header. Import that guy, and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include your header layout file in your activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ....>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    ....

 </RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...

<include
        layout="@layout/header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: If I include the header inside main activity you do realize that will make the header be constantly showing on the screen...

Comment: The header must be inside the navigation view so you can see it when it slides open but if i do what you suggest then all my views inside the header layout will be seen on the main page all the time

Comment: This is exactly what I was just saying. You HAVE TO load the view before you can findViewById on it.

Comment: If you want header for naavigation drawer then you can place the include tag for header layout inside NavigationView

Comment: Now that was more specific. Your prior suggestion would make all the contents be displayed on the "home"(main) activity

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including the XML that contains the button you are trying to find in the MainActivity XML. Try including that, and things should start working a bit better.

Edit for clarity:

You MUST load the XML that contains the button before you can call findViewById and actually get the button back. As your code currently stands, it is not getting loaded, and hence will never be found, and you will always be getting a NPE when you try to invoke any method calls after you findViewById.

Specifically:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_home">
*** <include layout="@layout/header" /> ***
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Why would i include the header layout inside MainActvity layout?

Comment: This is going to make all the views inside the Header layout be displayed over my content in the main activity...The header should only be inside the Navigation View

Comment: No matter where it is, you need to load the resource that contains the button before you can call findViewById. Since you didn't include enough code to completely show the structure of your screen, I answered as best as I could with the information given.

Comment: Also, my answer stands - you haven't loaded the file that contains buttonHeader before trying to access it. You need to load that XML in order for findViewById to work. Period.

Answer (score 0):

It is really late answer but maybe it can help another guys who get this problem.

You need to change your activity_main.xml codes like that: 
delete this in activity_main: 
app:headerLayout="@layout/header"

and include header layout. Like that:

from

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="#fff"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_home"/>
```

to

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_home"

 <include 
     layout="@layout/header"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="190dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```